# Getting posts by guid

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to get the post by it's guid.

I tried:

```
$post = get_post(array('guid' => 'foo'));
```

But that just returns the first post. (it's guid is not 'foo').

What am I missing?

Comment: Any specific reason *why* you need to do this. Why not use post ID

Comment: Right, obviously if I knew the ID I would use that.

Comment: Point taken, but how do you get the guid

Comment: I do feel that you are missing something somewhere. It would be nice if you can explain where you are doing it and why you are doing it and what should the expected outcome be.

Comment: @pieter - You're overthinking this. Assume I have the guid and nothing else.

Comment: Let's say you want to aggregate data from various external sources in a custom post type. Whenever you fetch and update this data you want to make sure you can update already existing posts and add only the new posts. The WP post ID is not useful because it has no relationship to the remote data. Using the GUID field for this purpose would be the obvious choice in my mind. 

It's unfortunate that the WP core devs didn't spot this use case. Apparently they only envisioned it being used in RSS feeds.

Comment: Another use case for storing a custom guid (not autogenerated by WP) is when mass importing pages from an older CMS. If you store the old URL in the guid field you can use this later to redirect to the new SEO-friendly URL via a simple PHP function hooked to a custom 404 handler.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can't pass GUID in `get_post()`.

I'd recommend you creating a function that returns a post ID from a GUID.

```
function getIDfromGUID( $guid ){
    global $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE guid=%s", $guid ) );

}

var_dump( get_post( getIDfromGUID('http://localhost/wpdev/?p=10') ) );
```

Comment: Ok. I was hoping to not have to drop into sql but I'll accept this if nobody comes up with something else.

Answer (score -2):

If you inside invalid argument/value, `get_post` will return first post data.

`get_post` only accept $post_id. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post

```
$post = get_post(7);
$title = $post->post_title;
```

If you want to specific filtering post, you can use `get_posts`. http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Example:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 1,
    'category'         => 4,
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_status'      => 'publish'
 );

get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: `get_posts` doesn't work for me either. I can't get a post by guid using either `get_post` or `get_posts`.

Comment: guid is a url in wordpress. If you want to retrieve post by slug, you can use get_posts().`$args=array(
 'name' => 'slug-name',
 'post_type' => 'post',
 'post_status' => 'publish',
 'posts_per_page' => 1
);`

Comment: No, I want to get it by guid. I can do it with raw sql but I prefer  using wp functions.